# Custom iOS keyboard: how to adjust the keyboard frame based on different iPads

Tags: swift, uiview, ios-keyboard-extension

**Here's the issue:**

So I'm building a custom iOS keyboard on iPad and naturally, I want it to work on multiple iPads. I have it set it up so that the UIView is made in an XIB and instantiated in my InputViewController. Right now, it's set to the frame that is specified in my XIB. I want the keyboard to be in the lower 3rd of my screen, covering the width of the screen so there's no overflow.

I've tried adjusting the frame in viewDidLoad() in my InputViewController, in awakeFromNib(), in viewDidLayoutSubviews(), and in viewWillAppear(), but when I've tried those, only a black screen appears.

Here's my code (the view is `bibleKeyboardView`)

```
class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {

    // A property to hold reference to a BibleKeyboardView object
    var bibleKeyboardView: BibleKeyboardView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // An instance of BibleKeyboardView is added to the controller's root inputView
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "BibleKeyboardView", bundle: nil)
        let objects = nib.instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)
        bibleKeyboardView = (objects.first as! BibleKeyboardView)
        guard let inputView = inputView else { return }
        inputView.addSubview(bibleKeyboardView)

        // controls visibility of the globe key
        bibleKeyboardView.setNextKeyboardVisible(needsInputModeSwitchKey)

        // adds automatic handle switching to glove key
        bibleKeyboardView.nextKeyboardBtn.addTarget(self,
                                                    action: 
                                                    #selector(handleInputModeList(from:with:)),
                                                       for: .allTouchEvents)

        bibleKeyboardView.delegate = self

        let screenBounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let screenWidth = screenBounds.width
        let screenHeight = screenBounds.height

        // This is the part that was causing my blank screen
        bibleKeyboardView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: screenHeight * 0.67, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight * 0.33)
}
```

Here's a pic of my keyboard view if that's helpful

[image]

Here's a pic of the keyboard when I try to assign `bibleKeyboardView.frame`

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated! This has got me stumped for the past few days.

Comment: What do you mean by black screen ? Can you show your current output ? Try `bibleKeyboardView.frame = self.frame`

Comment: @SharadChauhan Hi Sharad, it tells me that `Value of type 'KeyboardViewController' has no member 'frame'`